# Python 2 vs Python 3 for an IRC bot?

Tags: python, irc

Which would it make more sense to code an IRC bot in: Python 2 or 3? With 3 I heard you have to do extra stuff because it's unicode(?).

Comment: Depending on what you're doing with Unicode, you'd have to do less since Python 3 strings are all Unicode strings.  What makes "more sense" is subjective, since both can be used equally well to accomplish your task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't matter.
Python 3 is more Unicode compatible, but that's only a good thing.

The most obvious and visible thing changed in Python 3 is `print`. In Python 3.0 it is a function and requires parentheses.